# Ant Colony Algorithm for Edge Detection

Tags: image-processing

I am new to Image processing, and I am currently studying about how Ant Colony Algorithm can be used for feature detection. I went through the article in Wiki, and I have understood how they trace the shortest path from one node to another. But can some1 tell me how this is useful in edge detection?

Comment: Which Wiki are you referring to?

Comment: Great book describing many nature inspired algorithms is here. You can download it for free. (disclaimer: I have no affiliation)  http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/swarm/ant_colony_system.html

Answer (score 3):

Program your ants so that they deposit more pheromones on image gradients. After a while, they will tend to follow the image edges. After many iterations your pheromone map is your edge map.
In my opinion, ACO might not be the fastest algorithm available out there, but the behavior is interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am still very confused. I dont understand how they tend to accumulate over the high gradient pixels(edges) over the other areas, keeping in mind that they choose the shortest path from the start point to their goal-destinations. Could some1 break it up into simple steps? I know I am being naive but please do try to help me out.
Thank in advance.

Comment: -"How do ants tend to accumulate over the high gradient pixels(edges)?" You tweak their pheromon deposit so they do.
-"Ants choose the shortest path from the start point to their goal-destinations": No they don't choose anything, but this is the observed behavior when the pheromone deposit rate is homogeneous.